# Can some columns values of a dataset be reduced centred without using the machine learning package who requires dataset transformation into a Vector?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, statistics

I know that it's possible to center and reduce some values in *Spark*, using the methods of its machine learning package (`org.apache.spark.ml`).
But it's at the cost of doing multiples preparations first, to set data into Vectors.

It's not what I willing too. I would like to continue using my datasets as they are, without having to recreate them with their original columns back and the new values calculated from a lists of Vectors.

I'm not in a machine learning scenario at all.

Is there a way to reduce center some column values of a dataset with *Spark*, without going into the meanders of `ml`?

Comment: yes. You can work with custom udfs or RDD to do the same without ml functions(Vectors, estimators, transformers...). Calculate the column max value and the apply a simple udf that substracts it to each specific row element.

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez You deserve an upvote on your comment, but what you're writing is demoralizing.

Comment: I know, although I have worked in that way throwing away all the "magics" behind ml and doing raw Scala code. I would give a chance to dissasemble the vector, however...